# Why are my config settings inherited to the subdomain server block?

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate

I use nginx with a ssl wildcard certificate like that:

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com**

```
server {
    listen      443 default_server ssl;
    server_name 192.168.0.1 example.com;

    include /etc/nginx/ssl.conf;

    error_log   /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.ssl.log;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.ssl.log;

    root /var/www/example.com/;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        alias /var/www/example.com/example.com/;
    }
}

server {
    listen      80;
    server_name 192.168.0.1 example.com;
    return      301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

**/etc/nginx/ssl.conf**

The included `ssl.conf` looks like this:

```
ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/example.com.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/example.com.key;

ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/example.com_dhparam.pem;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers 'AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains";
add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
resolver 8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8 valid=300s;
resolver_timeout 10s;
```

My server block for the subdomain looks like this:

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/blog.example.com**

```
server {
    listen      443;
    server_name blog.example.com;

    error_log   /var/log/nginx/blog.example.com.error.ssl.log;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/blog.example.com.access.ssl.log;

    root /var/www/blog.example.com/;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:2368/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_buffering off;
        autoindex  off;
    }
}

server {
    listen      80;
    server_name blog.example.com;
    return      301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

https on the subdomain works fine but I'd like to know *why* it's working and why blog.example.com is inheriting the settings from example.com even though the ssl.conf isn't included in that server block.

I couldn't find anything in the nginx documentation about inheriting settings from default_server.

Is it just the expected behaviour with a wildcard certificate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Even though you don't show the main `nginx.conf` I suspect that your `ssl.conf` is included in the `http` level in nginx configuration.

Practically all `http` level settings are inherited to `server` blocks in nginx. See http://blog.martinfjordvald.com/2012/08/understanding-the-nginx-configuration-inheritance-model/ for more information on how directive inheritance works in nginx.

Comment: I should've included nginx.conf which contains the `http` block. The only files included there are `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` and `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` - My `ssl.conf` file isn't located in any of these directories.

Comment: Now that I looked at your configuration more closely, your `blog.example.com` is listening to 443 port, but without `ssl` specification. Therefore I think `https://blog.example.com` is served by the `example.com` server block, since that has `default_server` specified.

Comment: Good catch, I changed that - Thanks. There's still something unclear to me though: Why is blog.example.com displaying the blog and not the example.com site if it's choosing that (default_server) server then?

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that nginx acts in a bit odd way in situations like this, that is, using SSL configuration from `default_server` when no config exists elsewhere.